# Backbone/Javascript inspection: Can't grab models from collection

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Just starting out with backbone & I'm a little confused with how to retrieve models from a collection. To give an explanation, I have the following router method:

```
index: (date) ->
  @days = new Demomanager.Collections.DaysCollection(@options)
  @days.reset @options.days
  @days.fetch()
  @view = new Demomanager.Views.Days.IndexView(days: @days)
  $("#calendar").html(@view.render().el)
```

which passes to the following view:

```
class Demomanager.Views.Days.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/days/index"]

  initialize: (options) ->
    _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render')
    @options.days.bind('reset', @addAll)
    console.log @options.days
```

When I inspect that last line in the view (@options.days) in Chrome inspector, it comes back with DaysCollection, which includes a 'models' array complete with 36 entries (which is as expected).

However, when I change

```
console.log @options.days
```

to

```
console.log @options.days.models
```

I get an empty array, instead of the array with 36 models.

Finally, if I access the same object through the console itself (window.router.days.models), it shows the 36 models as expected.

So, in short: what's going on, and how can I access those models from within the view?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move your fetch to your view:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: new Demomanager.Collections.DaysCollection(options),
    template: myTemplate,

    initialize: function() {
        $("#calendar").html(_.template(myTemplate, {}));

        this.collection.fetch();
        this.collection.reset(null, options.days); // don't know how coffeescript works, but first arg here is models set not the options object

        this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
    },


    addAll: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(model) {
        $(this.el).append(new ChildView({model: model}));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its cause you make an asynchronous call. So when you log `options.days` in the constructor of your view the data wasn't loaded yet. It would be better to create your view in the success callback of `days.fetch`. Doing it this way you can also start an different view when the loading fails.